# how do I kill Entities with a custom nbt tag in minecraft 1.14.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a data pack that has a lot of custom entities, and I've been working on the creative mod e aspect of it. I'm trying to make a spawn egg the clears only a certain entity from the world. the entity has a special nbt tag called "Faulter", but when i run the use the spawn egg to clear the entity with the command I'm currently using, it does absolutely nothing.

Here is the command:

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:mooshroom,name=clearTest] run kill @e[type=minecraft:firework_rocket,tag=Faulter]
```

Is there any way to fix this? Or do I have rocks for brains?

Comment: What command did you use to give the NBT-tag? It looks like you're trying to use regular tags. What exactly do you expect the command to do?

Comment: the fire work is summoning a n armor stand that places a block to make a tower, i need to kill all fire works with the tag Faulter, and non other than those. the command i used to give the fire work  to the player is /give @a minecraft:firework_rocket{CustomModelData:12,Faulter:1b}

Comment: Then what is this part supposed to do? `at @e[type=minecraft:mooshroom,name=clearTest]`. And you really do use an NBT-tag, so you would use `nbt` rather than `tag`, so something like `@e[nbt={Faulter:1b}]` (or maybe `@e[nbt={tags:{Faulter:1b}}]`)

Comment: neither of those worked, mabe something is wrong with my game.

Comment: `at @e[type=minecraft:mooshroom,name=clearTest]` What is this part supposed to do?

Comment: it runs the command when ever a mooshroom with the name clearTest is spawned (so i can use spawn eggs as a clear function

Answer (score 1):

A fireworks entity that was spawned with an item given with the command `/give @a minecraft:firework_rocket{CustomModelData:12,Faulter:1b}` would have the `Faulter`-tag stored like this: `{FireworksItem:{tag:{Faulter:1b}}}`.

To kill all fireworks with that NBT-data you would use this command:

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:firework_rocket,nbt={FireworksItem:{tag:{Faulter:1b}}}]
```

You can use this command to `/kill` them if a mooshroom with the name "clearTest" is in loaded chunks in your world:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:mooshroom,name=clearTest] run kill @e[type=minecraft:firework_rocket,nbt={FireworksItem:{tag:{Faulter:1b}}}]
```

Comment: You can use `at` instead, but it's more obvious what you try to do if you use `if entity`.